# Отправка фото в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, python-3.10

Пишу бота для телеграм на библиотеке aiogramю Скажите пожалуйста, как отправлять фото в бота. Мануал либы не актуальный

Код отправки фото:

```
async def com_test(message: types.Message):
    await Bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=types.InputFile.from_url(URL))
```

Ошибка:

```
WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("Bot.send_photo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\endport_semegen\ls15\telega.py", line 73, in com_test
    await Bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=types.InputFile.from_url(URL))
TypeError: Bot.send_photo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

при `bot` вместо `Bot` вылазит ошибка аттрибута:

```
WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=AttributeError("module 'aiogram.bot' has no attribute 'send_photo'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\endport\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "D:\endport_semegen\ls15\telega.py", line 73, in com_test
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.chat.id, photo=types.InputFile.from_url(URL))
AttributeError: module 'aiogram.bot' has no attribute 'send_photo'
```

Comment: Может, вместо `Bot` вы хотели написать `bot`?

Comment: @andreymal нет, так оно выдает ошибку что в модуле aiogram.bot нет send_photo.

Comment: Мне кажется вы подключили модули айограма не верно. Перепроверьте подключение, и скиньте обновленную инфу